# Call to a member function show() on string on line 15

Tags: php

It worked a week before, I check if the objects are being defined with function `class_exists()` and they are both fine.

My error:

> Call to a member function show() on string on line 15

Which is a function of class `$logged_user` in `profile.php`

> echo $logged_user->show("Email");

My object `$logged_user` looks like this:

```
class LOGGED_USER
{
    private $DB;
    private $ID;
    private $Firstname;
    private $Surname;
    private $DisplayName;
    private $Gender;
    private $Birth;
    private $Email;
    private $Level;
    private $FolderPath;
    private $LastLogin;
    private $LastIP;
    private $LevelWord;
    private $ProfilePicture;
    private $ProfilePictureID;

    function __construct($DB_con, $ID, $Fname, $Srname, $Email, $Level, $FolderPath, $LastLogin, $LastIP, $Gender, $Birth, $DisplayName, $ProfilePicture, $ProfilePictureID){

        $BirthDay = strtotime($Birth);

        $this->DB = $DB_con;
        $this->ID = $ID;
        $this->Firstname = $Fname;
        $this->Surname = $Srname;
        $this->Gender = $Gender;
        $this->Birth = date("d-m-Y", $BirthDay);
        $this->Email = $Email;
        $this->Level = $Level;
        $this->FolderPath = $FolderPath;
        $this->LastLogin = $LastLogin;
        $this->LastIP = $LastIP;    
        $this->LevelWord = $this->sayLevel($Level);
        $this->DisplayName = $DisplayName;
        $this->ProfilePicture = $ProfilePicture;
        $this->ProfilePictureID = $ProfilePictureID;
    }

    //Function for calling "private" data
    public function show($atribut){
        return $this->$atribut;
    }
```

This object in `$logged_user` is beeing created in this object `$user` which works for registration and stuff for trying things as annonymous:

```
class USER
{

    private $DB;

    function __construct($DB_con)
    {
      $this->DB = $DB_con;      
    }

    //Function for creating LOGGED_USER
    public function useFactory($id){
        require_once "logged_user.php";

        $sql = $this->DB->prepare("SELECT us.ID, us.Firstname, us.Surname, us.Email, us.Level, us.Gender, us.Email, us.DisplayName, us.Birth, um.FolderHash, um.LastLogin, um.LastIP, uc.ProfilePictureID, up.Name, up.ID FROM Users AS us JOIN UsersMeta AS um ON us.ID = um.UsersID JOIN UsersConfig AS uc ON us.ID = uc.UsersID JOIN UsersPictures AS up ON up.ID = uc.ProfilePictureID WHERE us.ID = :id LIMIT 1");
        $sql->execute(array(':id' => $id)); 
        $sqlResult = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($sqlResult)){
            foreach($sqlResult as $data){
                return new LOGGED_USER($this->DB, $id, $data["Firstname"], $data["Surname"], $data["Email"], $data["Level"], $data["FolderHash"], $data["LastLogin"], $data["LastIP"], $data["Gender"], $data["Birth"], $data["DisplayName"], $data["Name"], $data["ID"]);
            }
        }else{
            return "Prázdno!";
        }

    }
```

And here I am creating the `$logged_user`and trying to call function `show()`:

```
session_start();
require_once "../config.php";
require_once "../objects/user.php";
$userFactory = new USER($db);
$userFactory->is_loggedin();
$logged_user = $userFactory->useFactory($_SESSION["user_session"]); //Returns new class (LOGGED_USER)

echo $logged_user->show("Email");
```

Comment: You are not checking the value of `$logged_user` and there is a case where it can be a string. You should check the type of `$logged_user`. Better yet, have `userFactory` throw an exception, then handle it properly.

Comment: But still I can't check returned value with isset() because I can't get the value. And I tried to call string value, boolean value, inteeger value, even datetime value and still the same response (error).

Comment: Just `var_dump($logged_user)` to see its value.

Comment: oh you are right! That crazy SQL task in factory (which returns LOGGED_USER instance) is empty, the if(!empty($sqlResult)) returns that the $sqlResult is empty... Does all the SELECTed items need to have some data in them? They are bunch of them they should be empty right now as Gender or DisplayName...

Comment: I think what you are saying is that some users that you expect are not showing up in your query? That is probably because of your JOINs. If a joined tabled doesnt have a record for that user it will be excluded from the query. Look at LEFT JOIN

Comment: Yes it's a new account that I am testing and there are missing some data in DB because they are not beeing set within registration as DisplayName, Gender etc but every table has a record (it has created row with UserID value there are just missing data in few collums). So I'll try the LEFT JOIN, thank you!

Comment: Well if I use the LEFT JOIN it spam me with errors like this:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Name'

Comment: FIXED! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `fetchAll` in your factory, as your criteria are `id` (the result always should be zero or one records). If you have no user with such `id` return `null`, so replace this:

```
$sqlResult = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($sqlResult)){
            foreach($sqlResult as $data){
                return new LOGGED_USER($this->DB, $id, $data["Firstname"], $data["Surname"], $data["Email"], $data["Level"], $data["FolderHash"], $data["LastLogin"], $data["LastIP"], $data["Gender"], $data["Birth"], $data["DisplayName"], $data["Name"], $data["ID"]);
            }
        }else{
            return "Prázdno!";
        }
```

with this:

```
$data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (empty($data)) {
    return null;
}

return new LOGGED_USER(
    $this->DB,
    $id, $data["Firstname"],
    $data["Surname"],
    $data["Email"],
    $data["Level"],
    $data["FolderHash"],
    $data["LastLogin"],
    $data["LastIP"],
    $data["Gender"],
    $data["Birth"],
    $data["DisplayName"],
    $data["Name"],
    $data["ID"]
);
```

Then in your code check if `logged_user` is `null`:

```
if ($logged_user = $userFactory->useFactory($_SESSION["user_session"])) {
    echo $logged_user->show("Email");
}
```

Comment: Still the same error:
"Call to a member function show() on string on line 10"

Comment: which is this echo:
if($logged_user = $userFactory->useFactory($_SESSION["user_session"])){
  echo $logged_user->show("Email");
 }

Comment: yes and thanks to comment above from @dan08 we know that the SQL in factory is returning empty value -> that if(!empty($sqlResult)) is returning empty... which is strange maybe because some data from that SQL are actually empty as DisplayName or Gender

Comment: because I am testing fresh account where are missing data in DB as Gender etc